# SSO functionality between two independent systems

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, keycloak

I have two different systems which need to interact with each other and we are playing the part of system in between (API) to make it happen. There is a certain requirement that if user is logged in System A and wants to go to System B, then it should communicate with our API to fetch the redirection url and redirecting to that url should automatically login the user from system A in system B. I want to ask how is it possible to provide that SSO functionality if the systems are independent and not under our control.

Furthermore, we are using Keycloak as an authorization server where clients can create and fetch the user access token via our API for communication. Can I somehow use the information in the access token to achieve above said functionality.

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about [sso-keycloack](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/12/07/how-implement-single-sign-out-keycloak-spring-boot)

Comment: This article refers to SSO logout. I want to establish a session so  System A can login the user from System B and vice versa. I want to mention that while System A implements oauth 2.0, System B has their own login mechanism which doesn’t follow any standard.

Comment: in service B, should you also provide some user details from service A that got login by authorization server  ? Or just get some data  without know,  who did it ?

Comment: Yes, I provide the details about the user to System B by using their API.